# JScript typed argument in cscript.exe

Tags: jscript, wsh

I'm trying to write a JScript function that accepts variable number of arguments that can be executed by cscript.exe. According to Microsoft documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yy9shf1(v=vs.90).aspx last function parameter can be an array, but it has to be typed array. Tried this and cscript.exe complained about syntax error near ":".

Then I tried simpler example with just one typed argument:

```
<job id="Test">
<script language="JScript">
    // Declare a function that takes an int and returns a String.
    function Ordinal(num : int) : String{
       switch(num % 10) {
       case 1: return num + "st";
       case 2: return num + "nd";
       case 3: return num + "rd";
       default: return num + "th";
       }
    }
    // Test the function.
    print(Ordinal(42));
    print(Ordinal(1));
</script>
</job>
```

I Saved it as "test.wsf" executed with :

```
cscript.exe //NoLogo test.wsf
```

Still got the same error. Is cscript.exe not able to use typed arguments (And variable arguments functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Plain) JScript executed by the C/WScript.exe hosts is (very) weakly typed. In particular, it does not support typed arguments (as it's cousin JScript.NET does). See [JScript functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t2k5yhw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I've never realized JScript.NET is only a cousin of (Plain) JScript.